# Way to make a pie chart using sum of certain cells in a column based on the tags in another column

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet set up as a type of checkbook and I was wondering if given a column called "Amount" which records the various dollar amounts of the individual transatction. And another column "Reason" which the reason for a transaction is written down "rent, eating out, etc". Could I make a pie chart that will add all of the values that are in the Amount column if they have matching reasons in the Reason column.

So if I have five Reason entries listed as "rent" can I then get the sum of each cell from the Amount column that is in the same row.

Essentially I want to have a resulting chart that shows the total I'm spending on each reason with the labels that match the reason category.

--Edit

[Heres an image of how my spreadsheet is set up currently with the solution of using filters to make a bar chart but I wonder if there's a better way to do this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrGYz.png)

Comment: Sorry i did not fully understood your goal. Could you provide a sample sheet with your expected output? and please confirm which solution are you looking for is it for google sheets or for excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a chart with Columns A (Amount) and B (Reason).
2. Create a filter with Column B (Reason)
3. Select/deselect the reason you want to include

You may also consider to filter with a [slicer](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9245556?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks, I used filters to make a new column of data that I then based a bar chart off of.